# Is there a way to match double quotes inside two double quotes?

Tags: ruby, regex

I tried the following regex, but it matches all the double quotes:

```
(?>(?<=(")|))"(?(1)(?!"))
```

Here is a sample of the text:

```
"[\"my cars last night\",
\"Burger\",\"Decaf\" shirt\",
\"Mocha\",\"marshmallows\",
\"Coffee Mission\"]"
```

The pattern I want to match is the double quote between the double quotes in `line 2`

Comment: Maybe [`(?<!\s*[[,]\s*)"(?![,\]])`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5cs*%5b%5b%2c%5d%5cs*)%22(%3f!%5b%2c%5c%5d%5d)&i=%5b%22my+cars+last+night%22%2c%0d%0a%22Burger%22%2c%22Decaf%22+shirt%22%2c%0d%0a%22Mocha%22%2c%22marshmallows%22%2c%0d%0a%22Coffee+Mission%22%5d&r=).

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks a lot. That works like a charm for regular expression site that you lined, but when I try this in my Ruby code it works differently and it doesn't pick it up. I guess the Regex has different syntax for ruby to match it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, I would say: **no**.

Given a string:

```
\"Burger\" \"Decaf\" shirt\"
```

How do you decide which `\"` is superfluous (non-matching)? Is this one after `Burger`, one after `Decaf` or one after `shirt`? Or one before any of these words? I believe the choice is arbitrary.

Although in **your particular example** it seems that you want all `\"` that are not adjacent to comma.

These can be found by following regexp:

```
(?<!^)(?<![,\[])\\"(?![,\]])
```

We start with `\\"` (backslash followed by double quote) in the center.

Then we use negative lookahead to discard all matches that are followed by comma or closing square bracket.

Then we use negative lookbehind to discard all matches that happen after comma or opening bracket.

Regexp engine that I have used can't cope with alternation inside lookaround statements. To work around it, I take advantage of the fact that lookarounds are zero-length matches and I prepend negative lookbehind that matches beginning of line at the beginning of expression.

Proof (in perl):

```
$ cat test
"[\"my cars last night\",
\"Burger\",\"Decaf\" shirt\",
\"Mocha\",\"marshmallows\",
\"Coffee Mission\"]"
$ perl -n -e '$_ =~ s/(?<!^)(?<![,\[])\\"(?![,\]])/|||/g; print $_' test
"[\"my cars last night\",
\"Burger\",\"Decaf||| shirt\",
\"Mocha\",\"marshmallows\",
\"Coffee Mission\"]"
```

Comment: Thanks @Mirosław Zalewski, this works and the details is very useful to understand what I was missing from the pattern. I thought the same issue, but this is after solving like 3 other weird patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the format of your string must be like this:

```
["item1", "item2", ... "itemN"]
```

The way to know if a double quote is a closing double quote is to check if it is followed by a comma or a closing square bracket.
To find a double quote enclosed by double quotes, you must match all well formatted items from the beginning until an unexpected quote.

Example to find the first enclosed quote (if it exists):

```
(?:"[^"]*",\s*)*+"[^"]*\K"
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZ6uC8/1)

But this works only for one enclosed quote in all the string and isn't useful if you want to find all of them.

to find all quotes:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|(?:\A[^"]*|[^"]*",\s*)(?:"[^"]*",\s*)*+")[^"]*\K"(?!\s*[\],])
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/fA7cM4/1)

Comment: Thanks alot @Casmir! Very helpful as well!